# Free up more File Cache in Activity Monitor like PURGE command

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix, caching, memcached

I have found a application has Clean Memory function.

[image]

I think it uses the original PURGE function, but after checking (using Activity Monitor), I see that it's likely to be more free File Cache than Purge command (or it can operate independently of the PURGE command). Please refer my experiment in below.

My question:

1. What it has used technology to make Clean Memory function (I have research https://opensource.apple.com/ for a week but did not find relevant information)?
2. (optional) The difference between Clean Memory function and PURGE command?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this.  That doesn't do anything useful but evict caches that were helping your computer perform better.  Any program that claims to clean memory is just snake oil.  Think about it this way, if the memory is really free, why bother having it in the first place, it's just a waste of power; instead, you want it holding things you might need from disk since you can always use it for something else nearly instantly down the road.

But, to answer your question: purge is in system_cmds.  It's source in 10.10 is available at: https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-643.1.1/purge.tproj/purge.c  You can look up the implementation of that system call in the xnu source.

As far as the tool you posted a screen shot of, there are a variety of awful hacks it could be using to make it look like memory has been freed.  It could allocate a bunch of memory, causing file cache to be discarded to make room, then free that memory.  Or perhaps walk the files on disk and madvise() them.  If you want know for sure, you can use debugging tools to introspect.  For example, the `sample` or `spindump` tools will show you the stacks and you might be able to tell from the stacks what system/library calls it is making.  Or, using dtrace (perhaps via the `dtruss` script), you could get a list of system calls the app is making.

Comment: Can you explain more detail about
"As far as the tool you posted a screen shot of, it may just be allocating a bunch of memory to force other things out of memory, or other similarly awful hacks. You might be able to use dtrace or sample to figure out what it's going exactly."